# How to set p < 1 in minkowski metric in KNN?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, knn

When I try to define p value less than 1 for minkowski metric in KNN algorithm im facing below error..
can any one let me know how could I tweak the p value less than 1 for minkowski metric

```
sc=StandardScaler()
p_kn =Pipeline([('sc',sc),('kn',KNeighborsClassifier())])
grid_kn={'kn__n_neighbors':np.arange(3,30),'kn__weights':['uniform','distance'],'kn__p':[1,2,0.5]}
KN=GridSearchCV(p_kn,grid_kn,'accuracy',cv=cv)
KN.fit(x,y)
```

getting below error

> ValueError: p must be greater than one for minkowski metric

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot, simply because for `p < 1` the Minkowski distance is not a metric, hence it is of no use to any distance-based classifier, such as kNN; from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_distance):

> For p ≥ 1,  the Minkowski distance is a metric as a result of the Minkowski inequality. When p < 1, the distance between (0,0) and (1,1) is `2^(1 / p) > 2`, but the point (0,1) is at a distance 1 from both of these points. Since this violates the triangle inequality, **for p < 1 it is not a metric**.